# Index a foreign key in Django Models

Tags: python, django, model, database-indexes

I want to index a very common query in a project that involves a CharField and ForeignKey. I have a bottleneck with this query and I am trying to optimize it. I have this:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

I added this to try to improve the performance:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['category', 'company']),
    ]
```

But the result is the same, the query is:

```
models.Bill.objects.filter(company=company, category='recibida')
```

Is there something else that I could improve? Is this indexing well done?

Comment: The order of columns in an index can affect performance, you should ideally have the column that will eliminate the most rows first, try changing the order so `company` is first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index you created is valid, but maybe not would you need. It creates a combined index of both fields and will only be used if you have a query which also used both fields.

If your query only accessing one of the fields at a time, the better approach is to add `db_index=True` after each field.

However, keep in mind that finding the best index for a query depends a lot on your context and the best approach is to use SQL EXPLAIN, e.g. with django-debug-toolbar to find it.